# Align php code left and right in html

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following php code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['email']) && $_SESSION['email'] == true) {
  echo "&nbsp You logged in as ", $_SESSION['email'];
 echo "<br/>&nbsp<a href='logout.php'>logout</a>";
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

This is a code for welcome and logout for logged in users but this is showing like both side by side. I need to align `echo "&nbsp You logged in as ", $_SESSION['email'];` to left and `echo "<br/>&nbsp<a href='logout.php'>logout</a>"` to right. How can I do this using html?

Comment: actually it appears on the top of the page . currently its not inside html.

Comment: Add it in html and add required styles to it

Comment: If you want nobreakable spaces you should use `&nbsp;` instead of `&nbsp`

Comment: can you share working demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them both in divs like

```
echo "<div class='div-left'> You logged in as " . $_SESSION['email'] . "</div>";
 echo "<div class='div-right'><a href='logout.php'>logout</a></div>";
```

Then style the divs using css so that one floats right and the other left.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'float' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\nurse\index.php on line 6

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat sorry I’ve edited the answer it should work now.

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat retype the double quotes at the end of line 1 around </div> I can’t type them properly on mobile

Comment: Replace those `‘` with `'` and `“` with `"`. I edited the code for you